# How do I find 4 linearly independent, perpendicular vectors in a hyper-plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality

Here's the question:

> Given the hyper-plane $x+2y-3z-w=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$,
>
> a) Find two independent, perpendicular vectors on the plane.
>       What I have done so far is:

$$
                           [1,2,-3,-1] \cdot [x,y,z,w] = 0 \\
                              => x=1, y=0, z=0, w=1
$$

So I've only managed to find one linearly independent perpendicular vector.

> b) Then find 3 independent, perpendicular vectors.
>
> c) Could you find 4 independent vectors on the hyper plane?
>
> d) Find a fourth vector perpendicular to the previous 3 in the hyperplane. Are perpendicular vectors always independent?
>
> e) What matrix, $A$, has the fourth vector as its null space?

Comment: Neither have you shown any effort on the questions nor have you stated the title correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
$$
V = H \oplus H^\top \\
H^\top = \{ t \, n \mid t \in \mathbb{R}, n = (1,2,-3,-1)^T \}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Use Gram–Schmidt or Orthogonal-triangular decomposition to find three orthogonal vectors that are on the plane defined by $n=[1\,\,2\,-3\,\,-1]^T$. In MATLAB,

```
[q,~] = qr([1 2 -3 -1]')
```

the last three columns of $\mathtt q$ are an answer to the second question. The answer the the third question is no: $n$ is the fourth perpendicular vector. There can only be four perpendicular vectors in $\Bbb R^4$. For the last question, I think $A$ would be the last three columns of $\mathtt q$ with $n$ in the null space.